# Best practice for default function values in PHP using const values in classes

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.3

PhpStorm is highlighting `$requestType` in the following piece of code in red, which I don't understand why. Maybe a bug in PhpStorm? Maybe is just not a good practice to define like that default function values?

```
class HttpClient
{
    const RequestTypes = [
        'DEFAULT' => 'default',
        'JSON' => 'json'
    ];

    public function makeRequest(
        string $requestType = self::RequestTypes['DEFAULT']
    ): Response {

        // The function

    }
}
```

The error message is `Default value for parameters with string type can only be string or NULL`.

Obviously the `['DEFAULT']` value is a string, but still giving an error.

What do you think?

Comment: Try PhpStorm 2017.1 RC

Comment: Well, thats a drastic solution, but it didn't work, is till highlighting it. Thanks anyway, now I'm using the latest version \o/

Comment: Have you set PHP Language Level 7 in your project settings?

Comment: Yes, currently is set on `7.1`.

Comment: Do you get any warnings if you run `php -l` against the file? I *think* that will use PHP's built-in linter. Some other editors/IDEs use that as the base of their PHP checking.

Comment: Thanks for it, I ran `php -l` and gave 0 syntax errors. So I start thinking is a bug in PhpStorm...

Comment: I think it is this PhpStorm bug here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35313

Comment: Thats it. You found it. Is what is exactly happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As commented by [Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965436/best-practice-for-default-function-values-in-php-using-const-values-in-classes?noredirect=1#comment73027263_42965436), this seems like an existing PhpStorm bug already reported at [Wrong evaluation of type](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35313#u=1488808698154). Thanks!

Comment: The question may get closed as "invalid" or similar, since your code *is* best practice, it's just the bug in PHP Storm marking it as an error.

Comment: I've flagged the question to be closed. Not 100% sure I chose the correct reasons, but… I don't think it's suitable for Stack Overflow now that we've found it in the PHP Storm issue tracker.